# PHP Change Array format with same index name

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hope all of you doing well.

Actually I have an array like in below.

```
[and] 
    => 
        Array 
            (
                [0] => Array ( [Model.qualifications LIKE ] => %"1":"1"% ) 
                [3] => Array ( [Model.qualifications LIKE ] => %"4":"1"% ) 
                [6] => Array ( [Model.qualifications LIKE ] => %"7":"1"% ) 
            )
```

The above array, I need to change like in below.

```
[and] 
    => array(
     [Model.qualifications LIKE ] => %"1":"1"%, 
     [Model.qualifications LIKE ] => %"4":"1"%, 
     [Model.qualifications LIKE ] => %"7":"1"%  
     )
```

Can anyone tell me how to do that.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes I was tried too much, but unfortunately did not solve this issue.

Comment: In each array, a unique key can only map to one value. You cannot have two values with the same key in the same array.

Comment: Since your index for the new array is the same, you can't map this array.

Comment: But Actually it is my requirement :(

Comment: This is impossible, and this is not logic. We can't help.

Comment: Is there any built in function in PHP, that we can use ??

Answer (score 0):

You cannot map the array with same key value. Rather you can have something like below if your key remains same:

```
[and] 
    => array(
             [Model.qualifications LIKE ] => array(
                                           [0] => %"1":"1"%
                                           [1] => %"4":"1"%
                                           [2] => %"7":"1"%
                                     )
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

If your all values in the array are different then you can put values as key and key as values and the can iterate as,

```
foreach($array as $key => $val){

}
```

Then use key and values as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Reason : Your array keys are same. You can do like this.

```
<?php 
$arr = array("and" => array (
            0 => array ("Model.qualifications LIKE" => '%"1":"1"%' ), 
            3 => array ("Model.qualifications LIKE" => '%"4":"1"%' ), 
            6 => array ("Model.qualifications LIKE" => '%"7":"1"%' ), 
            ));

$newarr = array();
foreach ($arr["and"] as $key1 => $value1) {
    $newarr[$value1[key($value1)]] = key($value1);
}
echo "Before : <pre>".print_r($arr,1)."</pre></br>";
echo "After : <pre>".print_r($newarr,1)."</pre>";
?>
```

**OUTPUT :**

Before :

```
Array
(
    [and] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Model.qualifications LIKE] => %"1":"1"%
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [Model.qualifications LIKE] => %"4":"1"%
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [Model.qualifications LIKE] => %"7":"1"%
                )

        )

)


After :

Array
(
    [%"1":"1"%] => Model.qualifications LIKE
    [%"4":"1"%] => Model.qualifications LIKE
    [%"7":"1"%] => Model.qualifications LIKE
)
```

Comment: Is there any built in function in PHP, that we can use ??